# how to create an element with specific center coordinate

Tags: jquery, html, position, coordinates

lets imagine I have the coordinate of a specific point in a `image` I mean I know it's center distance from left and top border ( EX: left:30px , top : 37px )!

now can I create an element ( a `div` ) in that exact position ?
actually I  want to give the position to jquery and it create the element for me ; and also Iwant to make it responsive and it points to exact point in any screens(PC,LapTop,tablet,phone ....)

Answer (score 1):

You can transform the div center along X and Y axis like this -

```
#elem{
    position:absolute;
    top:37px;
    left:30px;
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}
```

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/yaqsy3ju/)

**Note**: The position attribute is just for this example. It depends upon your placements of other elements how to position it.